# Integrate Detox with Fastlane

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, fastlane, detox

I did set up some `e2e` tests with `detox` for my `react-native` app.
I'm running those tests manually with the `detox test` command, but I cannot find (neither in the detox's issues, nor in Fastlane's documentation) a way to integrate these tests directly in Fastlane. None of [these options](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/#testing) seems to be adapted to what I'm looking for.

Anyone managed to implement this before or do I have to find a workaround for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

I solved it for iOS (`./ios/fastlane/Fastfile`) in the following way:

```
platform :ios do

  lane :e2e do
    Dir.chdir "../.." do # Navigate to the root of the project where the Detox files are placed.
      sh("detox build --configuration ios.sim.release")
      sh("detox test --configuration ios.sim.release --cleanup")
    end
  end

end
```

And Android (`./android/fastlane/Fastfile`):

```
platform :android do

  lane :e2e do
    Dir.chdir "../.." do # Navigate to the root of the project where the Detox files are placed.
      sh("detox build --configuration android.emu.release")
      sh("detox test --configuration android.emu.release --cleanup")
    end
  end

end
```